# Error in H2 Database, while running multiple tests

Tags: h2, liquibase, embedded-database

When I run each test individually then it passes. However, when I run all my test they fails. Below is a stacktrace for one such instance.

There are other test will fails too but have similar exception. I've tried all that was suggested here like using `MVCC=true` and `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`, but still NO GO.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.copyright.rup.common.test.integ.db.embedded.exceptions.EmbeddedDatabaseOperationException: Exception at liquibase update operation (classResourceAccessor is used)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: com.copyright.rup.common.test.integ.db.embedded.exceptions.EmbeddedDatabaseOperationException: Exception at liquibase update operation (classResourceAccessor is used)
    at com.copyright.rup.common.test.integ.db.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.liquibaseUpdate(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:391)
    at com.copyright.rup.common.test.integ.db.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.liquibaseUpdate(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:340)
    at com.copyright.rup.common.test.integ.db.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.getDataSource(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:274)
    at com.copyright.rup.common.test.integ.db.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.getObject(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:100)
    at com.copyright.rup.common.test.integ.db.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.getObject(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     77 change sets check sum
          work_type_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:c0c8b703ac39eb37665a5dd644ce7a12
          work_threshold_init.groovy::2012-05-03::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:bd533b8b09be4268b1fe97504bd6fa4e
          doc_path_filter_init.groovy::2012-05-08::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:c85d1a0012f4cf7e5d8a4c686ce82659
          doc_path_filter_limiter_init.groovy::2012-07-10::Alena Lakhava  is now: 3:5f7a9461182ee6ab3add8106e47405e5
          article_work_field_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:9841a4f8c52f68ab926fca5f168ad741
          chapter_work_field_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:fb3d017b5a3fe6789ab7fbc24e4e48c6
          monograph_work_field_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:40a323a8ac4631c1d18c83c214ebd4ac
          serial_work_field_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:ac9884af8e320db12adf4dec775df4e3
          unknown_work_field_init.groovy::2012-08-23::Alena Lakhava  is now: 3:48fd4b4eda29cf2a9efaac0ae37e92b7
          article_work_cluster_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:81de239c26df91a5d97d97369eb4d8bf
          chapter_work_cluster_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:ada1c0f7ce572949bbe438de1038cbb7
          monograph_work_cluster_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:918ebd67302a8d1d6e1713190e388853
          serial_work_cluster_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:dae5b3a7dd01f8000d7bd6bab2ae774d
          unknown_work_cluster_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:a51bdf3048e00f81b4fcb252a19afdd6
          work_media_type_category_init.groovy::2012-06-04::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:922e6e52392fc57c5983f8be9efd02e0
          work_media_type_init.groovy::2012-06-04::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:df6de50d4d6f63dbb85aa1a5dafc4b1b
          article_work_weight_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:f4e147ce3e11499d41e6936d6561329e
          chapter_work_weight_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:4514f9cec46e4da5394d1aae20b22013
          monograph_work_weight_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:c3bad504efd5872b08d152a5ddca6d28
          serial_work_weight_init.groovy::2012-05-02::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:c612131e966e0f2040f6e39e8278c234
          unknown_work_weight_init.groovy::2012-08-23::Alena Lakhava  is now: 3:aa63b9aa1df5a2fc0bb249bf90d5d8d0
          article_declarations_init.groovy::2012-05-03::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:d153805de41a3f904f5a3ce4aff2646a
          article_doi_rule_init.groovy::2012-05-03::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:e020f0fe8fc0ebd91862ce4a2c8e2652
          article_hostissn_rule_init.groovy::2012-05-03::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:bda67f8cdae5535bd74483ae1881abdf
          article_issue_rule_init.groovy::2012-05-03::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:bdeac2f4015e9476c44d287c07108108
          article_normedcontributor_rule_init.groovy::2012-05-03::Stanislau Halauniou  is now: 3:7187ab567461e2991835ef7facd28b13

Comment: What is you database URL?

Comment: My Database properties are currently set to:<property name="dataBaseProperties">
              <props>
                  <prop key="MODE">PostgreSQL</prop>
                  <prop key="DB_CLOSE_DELAY">-1</prop>
                  <prop key="TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT">1</prop>
                  <prop key="AUTOCOMMIT">OFF</prop>
              </props>

Comment: I think it is safer to append all properties to the database URL itself: `jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

### If multiple classes try to access same resources then it will give this error. It's always better keep them in a different package and then execute them

**

Answer (score 1):

[See the documentation for database URLs](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url).

You are using an in-memory database. Opening a second connection will get you a new database.

Instead, I suggest to use a persistent database, or a named in-memory database.

Comment: I am currently using a named in-memory database. Its jdbc:h2:mem:tests

Comment: Ok, that should work (does it?) when combined with `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`.

Comment: Do you think that DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE will solve the issue?

Comment: In memory databases are anyway gone when the process stopps, so: no.

Comment: Thomas, it has not made any change as such... Can you suggests some other way around.

Comment: Well, yes, try a persisted database first: `jdbc:h2:/data/db/tests`. If this work (and only then) try in-memory. And read the documentation.

Comment: Hi Thomas, recently I've noticed that when I use open multiple connection in one process (jdbc:h2:mem:test) then checksum changes. However, using jdbc:h2:mem: (unnamed private; one connection) doesn't change the checksum, but now the performance is too low.

Comment: It's hard to say, slow performance could have multiple reasons. Maybe using a profiling tool will help analyze the problem? That's what I usually do. See also http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#built_in_profiler

Comment: Thomas, is there a way that while using multiple connection in one process(jdbc:h2:mem:test), the checksum can be kept intact? Because the scripts where my databasechangelog is written is used by all 200 tests. Some of them fails if I open only one connection...so I have no choice than opening multiple conn.

Comment: Well, I don't know what this checksum is so I don't know. Maybe you want to open a new question?

Comment: I am now getting: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed: 77 change sets check sum